# Is password Hashed when manually entering into database possible using phpyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

This may be a bit of a random question and it may not even be possible, but is it possible to hash password when manually entering it into the database using phpMyAdmin?

I am using Laravel 5 and the built in Auth system currently but there will be <5 total users for this program that need access to the dashboard. So what I was told I should do is just delete the register controller and routes and manually enter the users into the database.

Is this even possible to do?

Also open to other solutions on how to complete this? I was told not to create a Admin user.

Comment: I think you mean HASH rather than Encrypt

Comment: Write a little PHP CLI script to `password_hash()` a string (the password). Echo it. Then copy paste the hash into a phpMyAdmin update of your user. Then tell your user what the password is. Not despritely secure though as you also know their password

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for pointing that out, you're right about that, I edited the question!

Comment: I didn't think of that, turns out one of my coworkers already had a CLI written for it, if you post as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a little PHP CLI script to `password_hash()` a string (the password).

Echo it.

Then copy paste the hash into a phpMyAdmin update of your user. Then tell your user what the password is. Not desperately secure though as you also know their password.

If you make it a little more comprehensive, enter `user account` and `new password`, you could also get the PHP CLI script to directly update your database with the new password as well.

You might also want to look at [Laravel Tinker](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-tinker) which you can run from the command live using `artisan`

Comment: Since the algorithm and cost are part of the resulting hash, as long as Laravel uses the standard `password_verify`/`crypt` or otherwise compatible API, you don't even need to match those parameters.

Answer (score -1):

For your purpuse you should do other things a simple hash will not work because laravel use a custom function called bcrypt and salted it with a random string.

You should create a seeder file with your users see the [Documentation of laravel for it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding)

And just seed your file your user will be created with expected password.

Thanks

Comment: Laravel [defers to the standard PHP `password_hash` API](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing#basic-usage), it's perfectly possible to replicate that easily.